# how to access signalr hub in azure webrole

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-web-roles, signalr-hub

I have a working SignalR Hub that contains some continuous running methods, they are managing sessions lifecycle, connecting sessions ... these continuous running methods are executed every X seconds using the `Timer` class. this is really not a good practice because of thread leaking, performance issues, locks ...

A better implementation would be to have a WebRole, and all those "worker methods" should go in the `WebRole.cs` file, witch makes a lot of sense, since this is the very purpose of roles in azure.

The probleme now, it can not get a working instance of the hub context using this code :

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AppHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.Message("hello from webrole");
```

`hubContext`  is instantiated (so not null) but even so, still nothing is broadcasted to clients. No errors and no exceptions !

I guess this is happening because the `WebRole.cs` and `Startup.cs` are instantiated in different threads ?

How can I access hub context in the `WebRole.cs` ?

Thank you.

Comment: ``I have a working SignalR Hub`` Where do you host your SignalR Hub server? Is it in an Azure Worker Role?

Comment: @FredHan its a web role

Answer (score 0):

> `hubContext` is instantiated (so not null) but even so, still nothing is broadcasted to clients. No errors and no exceptions !

I can reproduce same issue on my side. To broadcast the message to clients from `WebRole.cs`, you can try to install [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/) and invoke hub method to send message to clients. The following code works for me in the Compute Emulator, you can refer to it.

***WebRole.cs***

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);

            var hub = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection("http://localhost:57276/signalr/hubs");

            var proxy = hub.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            hub.Start().Wait();

            //invoke hub method
            proxy.Invoke("mySend", "hello from webrole; " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
        }         
    }


}
```

***ChatHub.cs***

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }

    public void mySend(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage("webrole", message);
    }
}
```

***Test result***

[image]